# add object to a relation of an user's relation with parse [Swift]

Tags: swift, parse-platform, relation

I'm using parse to build my first swift app. I made a lot of research about relation and trials but I'm still stuck. Here is the point : I have 3 classes to handle with : User, Day, Vape. The user has a relation which contains days : no problem with it. The problem is, each days object has a relation to Vape objects. But I don't know how to deal with this.. The example on parse's doc (https://www.parse.com/docs/relations_guide) doesn't talk that much on adding object to a object relation

Here is my code :

```
var vape : PFObject = PFObject(className: "Vape")
vape.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success : Bool, error : NSError?) -> Void in
  if success {
    var user = PFUser.currentUser()
    var relation = user!.relationForKey("jours")
    relation.query()?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objectss : [AnyObject]?, error : NSError?) -> Void in
        if let objects = objectss as? [PFObject] {
            println("There is \(objectss!.count) objects ")
            for object in objects {
              var relationVape: PFRelation = object.relationForKey("vapes")
              relationVape.addObject(vape)
              object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success : Bool, error : NSError?) -> Void in
                if success {
                  user?.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success : Bool, error : NSError?) -> Void in
                     if success {
                            println("saved")
                        }
                    }) 
                } else {
                    println("Error : \(error)")
                }
              })
            }
        } 
    })
  } else {
    println("fail svg vape")
  }
}
```

And my output is : 
**There is 1 objects 
saved**

But the vape isn't added to the relation (it is not set on parse.com) I get an "  Object not found." when I click on the relation

Where is the mistake? I thank you for any advice you could give

Comment: You shouldn't need to save the user as it hasn't changed in that code. Which relation are you testing, the user or day? And you get that error on the web interface? What about when you query?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Wain , Im testing the relation between Day and Vape (Day->Vape) . I get no erros with xcode but it doesn't add the object Vape on the Relation on parse.com. Do I need to change query()! in     relation.query()!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objectss : [AnyObject]?, error : NSError?) -> Void in [..] ? I thought if I perform this it gave me all the object contained in the relation. The point is, the Vape object is well saved in its class but not set in the relation

Comment: It should, and you can log `object` and `relationVape` to check.

Comment: In fact, the relation is well etablished between the Day and the Vape object, and between the user and the day separatly but when i clic on the relation "jours" of the user, and then the relation between the day and the vape is broken. Any idea? @Wain